Email Services and Salesforce Instance, e.g., NA250 in email address
I'm investigating implementing a feature using Email Services handled by Apex.  I noticed when I generated one in a dev org, it has the SF node Id, e.g., NA250, in the generated email address.  I would think that could be a major problem in production as if an org changes SF instances, any addresses that had been propagated anywhere would no long work.
Does anyone know in a production org if the SF instance will be in the generated URL of email services?
Below is an example of an email address generated by SF for an Email Service...
zzexper@2-8gzrr4gx98cmfsfmewi98nfikn6fw4e6y1er2ictejav3wwm8.6a-1kaniuam.na250.apex.salesforce.com


my experience is that despite an org changing instances, that the email services address continues to work as expected because it is bound to your org
